# PInvoke errors calling external SetWindowsHookEx and GetModuleHandle

Tags: c#, hook, pinvoke, setwindowshookex

I am trying to set windows hooks in my program to an external EXE. This will be used to monitor resizing/minimizing of the window, so I can resize my program similarly, docking to the window.

How do I get around error codes **1428** and **126** below?

When calling **SetWindowsHookEx** with a null hMod, I was getting this error **1428**. I get the same error if passing the current module (instead of IntPtr.Zero), which it seems to get correctly, as so:

```
IntPtr module = PInvoke.GetModuleHandle(null);
[...]
SetWindowsHookEx(...,...,module,...);
int error = PInvoke.GetLastError();
```

**1428** = *Cannot set nonlocal hook without a module handle*

I also tried to grab the external program I'm hooking as a module using **GetModuleHandle**:

```
IntPtr module = PInvoke.GetModuleHandle("communicator.exe");
int error = PInvoke.GetLastError();
```

But **error** is then set to:

**126** = *The specified module could not be found.*

I am using the following PInvoke statements:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(HookType hookType, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);
```

This is the procedure that is having the issue:

```
public void Install(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        uint threadId;
        uint processId;

        if (hWnd == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            threadId = (uint)AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId();
            throw new Exception("Lync thread not found!");
        }
        else
        {
            threadId = PInvoke.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out processId);
        }

        //IntPtr module = PInvoke.GetModuleHandle(null);
        //IntPtr module = PInvoke.GetModuleHandle(GetType().Module.FullyQualifiedName);
        IntPtr module = PInvoke.GetModuleHandle("communicator.exe");
        int error = PInvoke.GetLastError();

        m_hhook = PInvoke.SetWindowsHookEx(
            m_hookType,
            m_filterFunc,
            //Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle,
            //threadId);
            //IntPtr.Zero,
            //module,
            //Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(
            //                                System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0]
            //                        ).ToInt32()
            module,
            threadId);

        //IntPtr hinst = Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle);

        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681385
        // ERROR_HOOK_NEEDS_HMOD - 1428 = Cannot set nonlocal hook without a module handle
        error = PInvoke.GetLastError();
    }
```

Comment: You left the important bits out but the error code is clear enough, you cannot set global hooks with C# code.

Comment: What is the alternative? Do I have to write an external C++ DLL to handle it?

Comment: Also I thought providing a Thread ID to SetWindowsHookEx makes it a Thread Hook--not a global hook--so I thought it would be allowed.

Comment: The module handle has to be a handle to a DLL loaded into your process. That DLL must contain the filter function (an unmanaged function).  Windows will then load that DLL into each process in the system and call the filter function in each process as required.  So yes it needs to be in a C/C++ DLL to work.

Comment: "Windows will then load that DLL into each process in the system and call the filter function in each process as required." Oh okay, that makes sense, good explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use [GetModuleHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for an external process. It must be a module that has been loaded into the current process.

Comment: That's what I was guessing. Marking as accepted along with the explanation from @shf301. I'm guessing there isn't a way to load an extra EXE into the current process? It sounds like I'll have to do like he mentioned and have the hook filter in a separate DLL that is then passed to the separate communicator.exe process.

Comment: I believe you can use LoadLibrary to load an exe in the current process however I don't think this will allow you to set the hooks in another process the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue: 126 = The specified module could not be found.
I added missing message loop into my app and it start working again.

I'm using Hook func like this:

```
 hKeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(
                    WH_KEYBOARD_LL,
                    KeyboardHookProcedure,
                    Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(typeof(your_class_type).Module),
                    0);
```

and I added `Application.Run()` at tne end of the Main func

Comment: Did you mean to add this answer to this question?

Comment: Yes. I improved my answer with more detailed description :)

Comment: The fact that you also encountered error code 126 does not mean your solution applies here.