# How to port the C++ SetWindowsHookEx to C# or is this not possible?

Tags: c#, winapi, setwindowshookex

I was looking at the example in [Microsoft KB318804](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804) but they use the threadId of the "current" application!!!  I have some C++ code which works but we have to rewrite it, and I would prefer to re-write in C# while I am in there.  The one thing it does is get the threadId of the target application like so:

```
uint lastId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(targetHandle, IntPtr.Zero);
```

**no, GetCurrentThread is not the correct call as I am getting the thread id of a remote application which is what we do today AND what we want to do.  targetHandle is a handle to that remote application.**

I cast this lastId to an int and tried to wire up C# code but the SetWindowsHookEx returns 0 and fails. Only AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId() seems to work (even though it is deprecated, the replacement though doesn't work either).

Do I have to go with the C++ code then? or is there a way to get it to work in C#?

Currently we register the hookhandler in C++ with the other application and get events back.

Comment: The replacement for AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId()  won't work because it does not return the OS's thread id but a managed thread id. Could you tell use more about what you are trying to solve, and if you are using either Winform or WPF?

Comment: What type of hook are you using? All but the _LL hooks, when used against another application, require the hook to be in a separate DLL, so the hook must be in C++. You can only use C# for the _LL hooks, or (I think, but not absolutely certain) if hooking your own process.

Comment: @BrendanMcK  shucks, I think that is what I am finding out.  I have to stay in C++ and just rewrite it in C++ and keep it in C++.  :( :(.  oh well, I was just hoping since I have to rewrite it, I might be able to convert it but I guess not.

Comment: @Jf Beaulac - I edited the post as 2 people already miss that GetCurrentThreadId does not work for me since I need the remote apps thread id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked out the [pinvoke.net entry for `SetWindowsHookEx`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setwindowshookex)?

If [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx) returns `NULL`, you are supposed to call `GetLastError`, so in C# you should call [`Marshal.GetLastWin32Error`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error.aspx) (Assuming that [`DllImportAttribute.SetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.setlasterror.aspx) was included on the P/Invoke signature.)

From pinvoke.net:

**Signature**

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(HookType hookType, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);
```

**Calling**

```
IntPtr hHook;

using (Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
using (ProcessModule module = process.MainModule)
{
    IntPtr hModule = GetModuleHandle(module.ModuleName);

    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(HookType.WH_KEYBOARD_LL, hook, hModule, 0);
}
```

**Possibly related questions:**

- [PInvoke errors calling external SetWindowsHookEx and GetModuleHandle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774509/pinvoke-errors-calling-external-setwindowshookex-and-getmodulehandle)

Comment: so it reads like I cannot do it, correct?  This statement specfically I think implies I cannot wire my code into another application(though I can do so with C++)... "a hook must have a native dynamic-link library (DLL) export to inject itself in another process that requires a valid, consistent function to call into. This requires a DLL export, which .NET Framework does not support."

Answer (score 0):

Use this kernel32 call to get the current thread id:

```
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();
```

Comment: GetCurrentThreadId is "not" what I want.  I get the thread id of a completely different application, not my application.  The current C++ code works, and reading docs I think it will only work in C++ and this can't work in C+/.NET at this time.

Comment: @DeanHiller Sorry, I didn't get that from the original question.